# How parse checkbox values in server side(rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner in ruby + rails.

I have problem to get values in controler of checkbox with params[] of rails.

The Case:

I have simple form that that have checkbox and i want to sent reqular request to controller action with user checked values.
The problem that params[:rating] can have few values.

My case:
html user side:

```
<form id="ratings-form">
     <input name="rating" type="checkbox" value="G">G
     <input name="rating" type="checkbox" value="PG">PG
     <input name="rating" type="checkbox" value="PG-13">PG-13
     <input name="rating" type="checkbox" value="R">R
     <input type="submit" value="refresh">
</form>
```

**controller action code to parse checked values:** (get error 1. params[:rating] == nil or params[:rating] == string)

```
params[:rating].each  do |rat|
     p rat;
end
```

What should i change in the code to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this HTML

```
<input name="rating[]" type="checkbox" value="G">G
<input name="rating[]" type="checkbox" value="PG">PG
<input name="rating[]" type="checkbox" value="PG-13">PG-13
<input name="rating[]" type="checkbox" value="R">R
```

Then you should have an array in `params[:rating]`.